# Reinstalling .NET framework 3.5 in preparation for Websense install

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update, console-server, websense

I'm attempting to set up a Websense filter server but discovered that a previous tech person decided it would be a good idea to uninstall .NET framework 3.5 from the server. In the process of trying to reinstall .NET framework...I used the .net cleanup tool to remove any residual data from the previous installation. I have successfully reinstalled .NET 1.1 and 1.1 sp1 but am running into an error stating that I must use server manager to install .NET framework 3.5.

I understand that .NET framework 2.0 and 3.0 is innately built into the Server 2008 R2 OS and can usually be accessed via the features menu in Server Manager.

In the server manager console, I am getting a repeating message saying that the console cannot refresh until the computer is restarted. This error prevents me from making any changes to the roles or features of the server as well as preventing the completion of .NET framework 3.5 SP1. I have restarted the server several times only to get the same issue. I did  some research into the console refresh issue and discovered some references to updating Windows Update and/or reinstalling WUA 3.0. I downloaded and have been attempting to manually reinstall WUA 3.0 but get a "0x80070bc9" error message to that as well.

It's getting to the point that I'm not sure which issue to address first. Any guidance or input would be infinitely appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried updating Windows Installer?

Comment: No, I have not. I will update Windows Installer and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could try running this from an admin command prompt:

```
sfc /scannow
```

That should give you "There is a system repair pending which requires a reboot to complete."

If that is the case, delete `C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml` and reboot. Once it reboots, re-install the WUA 3.0 client and reboot again.

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135